# How to use a MIDI keyboard on a laptop?

Tags: piano, software, keyboard, midi

So I recently found a Suzuki SPW-49 MIDI keyboard in my home and want to play it. I know a computer is needed to play any sounds using the keyboard, but every time I seem to plug it into my computer using the USB port it does not have any sort of automatic recognition. I have several softwares such as SimplePiano and VirtualPiano, but none of them seem to recognize the keyboard.
Also, the output sound on my only computer does not work, so does this mean that there is no way for me to use the keyboard? The keyboard does seem to have segments on the side that look like speakers.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Some MIDI devices are 'class compliant' and work without a driver - others need a driver to be installed on your computer. If you don't have the manual, perhaps contact Suzuki for advice?

Answer (score 1):

Wriiting an answer since I can't comment yet.

Since the suzuki is an old Midi controller, I don't expect plug and play facilities. Windows too might be incapable of finding an appropriate driver.

A quick search for a driver on Google should help. Just search your model number.

Good luck with it.

Comment: Anyway, this is too detailed for a comment.  Welcome!